# Which European countries don't require a transit visa for Indian citizens travelling to Cuba?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens

Which are the European countries that will not require transit visa for the Indian citizens travelling to third country (Cuba)?

As I have found in the website of Russia and The Netherlands that they don't require transit visa.

Comment: Not sure I'd want to fly a route near/through the Russia/Ukraine area right now.

Answer (score 2):

In the EU, the [UK requires a transit visas for Indian citizens](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no). In the Schengen area, the Czech Republic, Spain, France, and Germany also require transit visas (cf. [official table from the EU commission](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf)). All other Schengen countries (including the Netherlands, Belgium, Switzerland, Portugal, etc.) allow visa-free transit. [Ireland does too](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html). Beware there are other rules and exemptions to consider, see [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Countries like Russia or the Ukraine are not part of the EU and I don't know what their rules are.

Comment: Russia doesn't require a transit visa.  Transiting through Ukraine is logistically more difficult since I can't find flights direct from Ukraine.

Comment: Thanks to all for answering my queries. So just i have to my find the flight from these countried that dont require visa to transit.

Comment: These are the following Countries that do not requires any visa to transit for INDIAN Citizens.1.Austria 2.Belgium 3.Netherlands 4.Luxembourg 5.Cyprus 6.Denmark 7.Estonia 8.Greece 9.Hungary 10.Italy 11.Lithuania 12.Portugal 13.Switzerland 14.Ireland 15.Russia

Comment: I find the route from Del-Mos-Hav-Gcm.